# Tools for scaffolding a .NETCore WebAPI project with Entity Framework and integration tests

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm making the switch from frontend/Angular to backend/.NETCore. The biggest hurdle I've had is understanding what goes into scaffolding, especially when it comes to integration testing a WebAPI project and Entity Framework migrations.

Are there scaffolding tools similar to Angular Cli that promote good practices around things like setting up new projects or adding new classes in an organized, easily maintainable way?

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is `dotnet new` which gives you both project templates (`dotnet new razor`, `dotnet new mvc`) as well as item templates (`dotnet new page`).

For entity framework, there is `dotnet ef` to help creating database contexts for existing databases (`dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold`) as well as managing migrations (`dotnet ef migrations …`).

Answer (score 1):

I create new .NET Core projects using Visual Studio 2017 so the IDE automatically sets everything up in organised and maintainable way. It is certainly possible to do this in similar way to Angular CLI with .NET Core CLI. If you're creating .NET Core 2.x project you can find all the required commands [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/?tabs=netcore2x). For example; `dotnet new webapi --name MyWebApiProject` creates a web api project. To add Entity Framework you can use EF Core .NET Command-line Tools in similar way. Please find all EF Core commands [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet).